# Batch file: map a FTP server

Tags: dictionary, ftp, net-use

I want to add a a network location / map a drive to my ftp server. 
I know how to do this manually but i would like to have it in a batch file.

im guessing its along the lines of:
"net use x: \[server IP]\ /username:[username] /Password:[password] /p"

and how can i assign a name for it with this?

Thanks!

Comment: So what's wrong with what you posted as a "guess"? Does it work for you?

Comment: it kicks back with error 67 or it will return the syntax list for Net Use without anything referring to ftp or naming.